# onclick fire only after three clicks

Tags: android, html, kendo-ui

I have phonegap application at html5, with kendo ui. 
My button work fine on browser, but at android device I need to click three times to fire the alert.
This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="view" data-title="Login/Sign-up"
        id="view-transitions-login" data-transition="overlay:left"
        style="background-color: white;">

        <input type="button" id="logButton" value="login"
            style="width: 100px; height: 60px" />
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#logButton").click(function() {
                alert(33);
            });

        });
    </script>

    <script>
        var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't figure out your problem [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TbsC3/)

Comment: At browser it work fine, but on device it make trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm found the answer.
I used the latest version of kendo.all.min, and That made the problem.
I changed the file and everything works as it should.